# how to get value from array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

In laravel i get this type of array from where query.
i want to get only those menu where parent is 0;

```
 $memus  = Menu::where('parent', 0)->get()->toArray();

 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [name] => Movies
                [parent] => 0
                [deleted_at] => 
                [created_at] => 2015-04-07 02:48:48
                [updated_at] => 2015-04-07 02:48:48
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16
                [name] => zxcvxc
                [parent] => 0
                [deleted_at] => 
                [created_at] => 2015-04-07 02:53:26
                [updated_at] => 2015-04-07 03:03:39
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17
                [name] => alsdkf
                [parent] => 0
                [deleted_at] => 
                [created_at] => 2015-04-07 02:53:41
                [updated_at] => 2015-04-07 03:02:04
            )

    )
```

So how to get particular value from this array
i have tried `echo $abc->name` and `echo $abc->id`
but not access

Comment: Use `foreach` loop and you have to get it as array as `$menu['name']` or if you want to use it as object then don't convert the result using `toArray()` then you can fetch it as `$menu->name`.

Answer (score 11):

You can just do this:

```
echo $memus[0]['name'];
```

Or if you want all of them

```
foreach ($memus as $memu) {
       echo $memu['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The arrow `($object->property)` notation is for objects.

The notation for accessing array elements is `$array[$index][$key]`.

So in your case, to access the name key in your second array would be:

`echo($menu[1]['name'])`, in your example this would echo the string 'zxcvxc'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections in laravel 5

```
collect($arrayName);

$filtered = $arrayName->where('parent', 0);

$filtered->all();
```

Hope this will help. If not please let me know.

Comment: `$collection->firstWhere('parent', 0)` to get the item. [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-first-where)

Answer (score 1):

To get a particular value

```
{{memus[0]->id}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line for me worked

```
  $memus  = Menu::where('parent', 0)->get()->toArray();
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($memus as $s) {
        array_push($arr,$s->buy_product_id)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access some array's data just do
`$array_name[index]->key` in the controller or in the view.

Index is usually an integer and the key is what you are looking to extract.
For instance, we would do this on your array: `$menu_zero = $menus[0]->id;`
it would give us 13 and `$menu_name_zero = $menu[0]->name;` would give the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

For single item you can do this:

```
echo ($menus[0]['parent'] == 0) ? $menus[0]['name'] : '';
```

With `foreach` loop:

```
 foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        if($menu['parent'] == 0){
            echo $menu['name'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query :: $firstCategory = ProductCategory::select('id')->offset(0)->limit(1)->get()->toArray();

How to display value :: $firstCategory[0]['id'];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).